# Void-Touched Sorcerer's Voidfield ability

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, archetype

I'm trying to figure out how Voidfield works, which is the second ability [Void-Touched](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/mutated-bloodlines---paizo/void-touched) get.

> Voidfield (Sp): At 9th level, you can create an area influenced by the
>   black void. This ability acts as an ice storm, except the area is also
>   subject to deeper darkness for 1 round per four sorcerer levels. You
>   may use this ability once per day at 3rd level, and one additional
>   time per day for every three additional levels.

Fairly obvious this has some errors in it.  The first issue is what level you get it at, and I've decided it's 3/day at level 9 with another use every 3 levels after.

The two spell effects (Ice Storm and Deeper Darkness) have an odd interaction however, due to the way the sentence is setup.  Ice Storm lasts 1/round a level but from the way the sentence is structured, I can't tell the combined spell effect lasts 1 round every four levels or if the ice storm lasts 1 round a level with the darkness effect lasting 1 every 4.  **What's the correct way to read this sentence to understand how the effect works?**

Research on [the topic](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ngt0?Voidfield) gave some good ideas, but there doesn't appear to be an FAQ resolution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Voidfield*'s effect

The [*ice storm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm) effect's duration is 1 round, just like the spell [*ice storm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm). Simultaneously overlaying the *ice storm* effect is the [*deeper darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deeper-darkness) effect, which is like the [*deeper darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deeper-darkness) spell **except** that this [*deeper darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deeper-darkness) effect affects the same 20-ft.-radius-and-40 ft.-high cylinder as the *ice storm* effect (instead of the [*darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness) spell's normal area of a 20-ft. radius ) and that the [*deeper darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm) effect's duration is 1 round per 4 sorcerer levels (instead of the [*deeper darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm) spell's normal duration of 10 min./level), the first round of the duration occurring simultaneously with the [*ice storm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-storm) effect.

#### *Voidfield*'s uses per day

Given the reluctance of *Pathfinder* to grant repeated use of even mid-level spell-like abilities, I'd argue that the mistake is the *once per day at 3rd level*, and that the number of uses should say, instead, *once per day at 9th level*. Such a reading would allow a level 9 user to use the ability 1/day, a level 12 user 2/day, a level 15 user 3/day, and a level 18 user 4/day

However, being able to use *voidfield* another 2 times per day is unlikely to unbalance all but the most fragile of games, so, overall, your house rule is as good—if a bit more generous than—the house rule I'd make.

Comment: I agree on the uses per day, when compared to other mid-level spell-like abilities.  There is no definitive answer to this, but this seems reasonable when compared to other powers.  As of this writing there is no FAQ or author clarification I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

There are no errors in the description, and your reading is correct.

At 9th level, you can use the power three times per day.  The '3rd' level listed is just to establish when the pattern of 'every three additional levels' starts.  It could also have been '2nd level and 1 additional time for every three additional levels', in which case the pattern would have been 2/5/8/11/... instead of 3/6/9/12/...

As for the duration, the *ice storm* effect will last for nine rounds levels at level 9, while the *deeper darkness* effect will last two rounds.  At level 10 it will be 10/2, at 11 it will be 11/2, at 12 it will be 12/3, etc.